# How to convert from Wei to Ether in React?

Tags: solidity, react

In React, I use a Web3js call function to get a value. The returned value is in Wei. However, I want to render it in Ethers. What would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In web3.js 1.0, use this:

```
web3.utils.fromWei(number [, unit])
```

[doc](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html)

Comment: Is there any non web3 version? I am using MetaMask.

Answer (score 21):

I think you're looking for `fromWei`. In web3.js 0.2x.x:

```
web3.fromWei(n, 'ether')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For some reason, I'm getting "Cannot read property 'fromWei' of null"

Comment: Is `web3` null?

Comment: No, the function returning Wei works. I imported Web3 from 'web3', and set a current provider.

Comment: let web3 = new Web3(Web3.currentProvider)  after which {web3.fromWei(price, 'ether')}

Comment: And now, the error is: new BigNumber() not a number: [object Object]

Comment: So... are you still getting the `null` issue? Or has that been resolved?

Comment: And if so, what code is triggering the new error?

Comment: I first imported Web3, then initiated with a current provider, then applied the function you've provided. The issue now is "new BigNumber() not a number: [object Object]"

Comment: What's the value of `n` you're passing? Sounds like it's some sort of object.

Comment: It's a Drizzle component <ContractData contract="TestContract" method="valueOf" methodArgs={this.props.id}/> which returns the value mapped to the component's ID

Comment: You're passing a Drizzle component to `fromWei`? What?

Comment: Try just hardcoding a number to verify that `web3.fromWei` does what you want: `web3.fromWei(1e18, "ether")`. Then figure out what the actual value you want to pass in is.

Comment: <ContractData contract="TestContract" method="valueOf" methodArgs={this.props.id}/> - this returns the value, it's a Drizzle component (new framework from Truffle team). I'm storing the response in a var price, which I'm passing to fromWei(price, 'ether')

Comment: I just did, web3.fromWei(1e18, "ether") works. returns 1 Eth.

Comment: So again, what is the value you're passing into `web3`? (Try doing `console.log(price);`.)

Comment: The 'price' value that the Drizzle component returns is 32000000000000000. `console.log(price)` passed to fromWei returns 0 :/

Comment: I thought you said it produced an error: `new BigNumber() not a number: [object Object]`? Now you're saying it produces no error but returns 0?

Comment: I think I'll let you finish debugging your code. :-) `web3.fromWei` works if you pass in the correct value, and the rest is just debugging for you to do.

Comment: Sure, thanks for answering, I'll post more details to the answer once I'll figure it out.

Comment: Oh, I think you did something like `web3.fromWei(console.log(price), ...)`? Don't do that. Just do `console.log(price)` to see what its value is.

Comment: So I figured out one part, web3.fromWei(32000000000000000e-1, 'ether') works just the way I need it to. But now I can't figure out how to use variable "price" instead of 32000000000000000 :D

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74051/discussion-on-answer-by-smarx-how-to-convert-from-wei-to-ether-in-react).

Comment: change `web3.fromWei` to `web3.utils.fromWei` ;)

Answer (score 4):

**web3.utils.fromWei**(yourValue, 'ether')

^^^
You must use the utils library. If you're getting the weird, TypeError: web3.fromWei is not a function and you're trying to console log the output, try setting the function call to a constant and then console logging that constant. Like so...

yourValue = returned amount of ether

returnValue = web3.utils.fromWei(yourValue, 'ether')

console.log(returnValue)

Answer (score 2):

**You have**

```
web3.utils.fromWei('1', 'ether');
```

This results in the following: `0.000000000000000001`

This assumes that your parameter is 1 wei and you want to convert it to ether.

**You can also do it the other way around**

```
web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether');
```

This results in the following: `1000000000000000000`

This assumes that your parameter is 1 ether and you want to convert it to wei

In both cases the second parameter is optional and defaults to "ether".

You can use all available ETH units as second parameter (e.g. gwei, shannon, szabo, etc.).

For more information you can check the [official documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-utils.html#fromwei)

Answer (score -1):

**Fetch Balance in eth complete syntax.**
{
`var web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);`
`await window.ethereum.send("eth_requestAccounts");`
`var accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();`
`var account = accounts[0];`
`var balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(account);`
`var amount = await web3.utils.fromWei(balance);`
`console.log(amount);`
}